# NoMethodError undefined method 'merge' when running RSpec integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am following **Micheal Hartl's Ruby on rails tutorial 2.3 Edition** and I have followed the steps for the integration tests correctly. in **/sample_app/spec/integration** I have a file named **layout_links_spec.rb** which looks like this.

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Layout links" do
 it "should have a Home page at '/'" do
  get '/'
   response.should render_template('pages/home')
  end
 end
```

When i do

```
$ spec spec/
```

I am getting the following error

```
1)
NoMethodError in 'Layout links should have a Home page at '/''
undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass
 /home/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/integration/layout_links_spec.rb:4:

Finished in 0.060225 seconds

1 example, 1 failure
```

Please help me with this error

Comment: Please run the spec with `rspec spec --backtrace`.  That will print off the full backtrace and give us more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this question, it looks to me like you are following the 1st edition of his tutorial. If so, the command he used to generate the integration test is on page 178, Section 5.2.1

```
rails generate integration_test layout_links
```

The result is a file under **spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb**

---

If you browse the source code for his app, there isn't a **spec/integration** folder. Take a look [here](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app/blob/master/spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb) and see if this helps. Hope so.

**PS:** He comments "In RSpec, integration tests are also called *request specs* - the origins of this terminology are obscure to me."

In the RSpec [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-11/docs/request-specs/request-spec), I found this: Request specs provide a thin wrapper around Rails' integration tests, and are designed to drive behavior through the full stack, including routing (provided by Rails) and without stubbing (that's up to you).

Comment: I have that command in page 162 in my book which asks me to first create a spec/integration directory and then run the command "script/generate integration_spec layout_links"

Comment: I see. It looks like that is in the Rails Tutorial for Rails 2.3.x while the code I am referencing is from the Rails 3.0.x edition.